# How do I cancel GitHub Pages redirection?

Tags: github, redirect, github-pages, cname

I created a web page using GitHub Pages. I added the custom domain by following the `Settings>Pages` path. The page redirect was successfully performed by creating the `CNAME` file.

[image]

I wanted to cancel the page redirect after a while. Therefore I removed the **CNAME** file and followed all the steps mentioned in the documents. But I was not able to cancel the page redirect. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the website redirect is saved in the browser's cache, the redirect will continue even if the redirect is cancelled via the `Settings>Pages` tab on GitHub; this will automatically cause the `CNAME` file to be deleted. The way to solve this problem:

1. Remove the previous redirect by going to `Settings>Pages` on GitHub.
2. Rebuild the page via the Actions tab on GitHub.
3. Click the <kbd>F12</kbd> while the browser is open.
4. Long click on the refresh button on the browser.
5. Select the `Empty Cache and Hard Reload` option.

[image]

When you try to enter the website again, you will see that the redirect has been cancelled.