# I renamed a repository, how do I now delete the redirect?

Tags: github

I pushed a local repo to github and managed to end up a repo called "src".  I solved that by renaming the repo on the github side (Settings -> General -> Repository name) and fixing up the local config (git remote set-url origin).

This all works, but github "helpfully" created a redirect from "src" to my new repo name.  So now I've got

```
https://github.com/roysmith/src -> https://github.com/roysmith/rs-lint
```

I don't think that breaks anything, but it's annoying and seems like it's laying a trap for future-me if I accidentally repeat my mistake and push some other new local repo to a remote src.  Is there any way I can delete the redirect?

Comment: See the stack overflow page [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71179035/how-do-i-cancel-github-pages-redirection#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=Since%20the%20website%20redirect%20is,Cache%20and%20Hard%20Reload%20option.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71179035/how-do-i-cancel-github-pages-redirection#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=Since%20the%20website%20redirect%20is,Cache%20and%20Hard%20Reload%20option.).
Let me know if this helps.